# Hive Access Issue - Not able to access Hive CLI without Write Access

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hadoop and Hive so this question may be too basic

I am using Hadoop as a non-admin user, i.e., I do not know the hdfs, root or superuser passwords. My objective is to just query the Hive tables and probably do some simple analysis but not write in the hdfs or create any new tables.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.2.0-2950/0/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=b001195, access=WRITE, inode="/user/b001195":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
```

I can see that this error says that this user does not have write access to hdfs.  But I am not trying to write anything.  Can anyone please suggest what changes I can make through my access level to remove this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the cluster kerberized?

Comment: Yes, i think the cluster is kerberized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to find an hdfs directory that has 777 permissions (/tmp maybe):

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

Then once you find that directory, add the following to the command you connect to hive with:

```
--hiveconf hive.exec.scratchdir=<DIRECTORY FOUND IN PREVIOUS STEP>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this but it now gives me a different error: Permission denied: user=b001195, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/hdfs/.hiveJars":hdfs:hdfs:drwx------.  Please suggest what steps I can take.  I am sorry for the brief message due to character limitation.

Comment: No problem friend!

Comment: @user3750170 - Please open it as a different question

Comment: @PaulBack - Please add an explanation to you answer of why write privileges are needed ("But I am not trying to write anything"). Thanks.

Comment: The reason you need write access is that hive generates intermediate files in hdfs since MapReduce (the underlying data processing engine) is file-based, plus it stages some jars from the client in hdfs.  Can you paste the `hdfs dfs -ls` output of the argument you set for `hive.exec.scratchdir`?

Comment: Hi Paul, the second issue i was facing was due to an execute access on hdfs which is now resolved by my stem admin.  You first answee does  resolve the issue in the post. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in kerberized environment, you have to create principal with your user name in kerberize db and you have to open a ticket,

**Note**

You'll need Kerberos admin privileges for that.

**Reference**:

https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/admin_commands__/kadmin_local.html

Then you are good to get in Hadoop environment but, to read/write/execute Hadoop directories, you have to be either:

- be the owner of the directory
- be in the group of that directory
- the directory has to give permission to other groups
- be in Hadoop super user group, (which you are not as you mentioned)

Based on  my experience with Hadoop, Linux or even Windows servers, majority of problems is related to permission issues.

I'd like to add my quote about this :)

> When we achieve living in a world where we don't have and need any keys, locks, gates, safes, passwords, user permissions,or any security related time/money wasting obstacles, We can say we are living in a perfect society